# RestClient undefined method `delete_if' for #<String:0x4b699a8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

OK so, I'm using RestClient and sending this:

```
{"x_select_params":["account.*"],"domain":"thedomain"}
```

Via

```
response = RestClient.get servername, @payload
```

And I get

```
undefined method `delete_if' for #<String:0x4b699a8>
```

In response.

I know that the request is good as it works fine when I use the Chrome rest client extension, I'm thinking that RestClient is having an issue in parsing the response, which is supposed to look like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 4035,
        "first_name": "Chris",
        "last_name": "Penta",
        "status": "PENDING",
        "domain": "thedomain",
        "default_account_id": 111315004004010,
        "primary_alias_id": 131090,
        "accounts": [
        {
            "id": 111315004004010,
            "urn": "111315004004010",
            "balance": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "currency_code": 840
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in RestClient that needs patching? And if so, anyone know how to fix?

Thanks...Chris

Answer (score 3):

I found this error when the headers were in a json format.  They needed to be a hash to work.